# Homeomorphism-Topology

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $f:(X,\tau_1) \to(Y,\tau_2)$ be an injective and surjective continuous function. If $X$ is compact with respect to $\tau_1$ and $Y$ is Hausdorff with respect to $\tau_2$ then how can we show that $f$ is a Homeomorphism?

I know that every bijective bi-continuous mappings are homeomorphic. Here it is given that this mapping is bijective and continuous, how can I show that the inverse map is continuous?

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** All you need to show is that $f$ is either open or closed to have that it is a homeomorphism.

Note that the continuous image of a compact set is compact; and that closed sets in a compact space are compact.

Comment: But how can I use the fact that Y is Hausdorff to say that the map is either closed or open?

Comment: Compact sets in Hausdorff spaces are closed.

Comment: thanks alot Asaf Karagila:)

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \in \tau_1$ be a closed. Since closed subset of a compact space is compact so it is compact. Now continuous image of a compact set is compact so $f(A)$ is compact. Finally by using the theorem - Every compact set of a Hausdorff space is closed we will get $f(A)$ a closed set . Hence mapping is closed and prove is done.

I hope this will help you.